# Optical devices for micro meter photons?

Tags: photons, quantum-optics, fiber-optics

Are there all the common optical devices like beam splitters, mirrors, polarizers, fibers, etc for photons with a wavelenght in the range of micro meters?

If so, how broad can the bandwidth be for the optical devices to work properly?

Consider for example a photon with a mean frequency of $10^{12}\,\text{Hz}$ (i.e. a wavelength of $300\,\mu\text{m}$). Will problems occur if the bandwidth of the photon is also in the range of $10^{11}\,\text{Hz}$ or $10^{12}\,\text{Hz}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This falls into the "terahertz band" which has been getting a lot of attention recently.  I'm not an expert in that area, but I can suggest you search "terahertz optics".  I note that [Newport Corporation has a line of terahertz components](https://www.newport.com/Terahertz-Optics-Selection-Guide/1026123/1033/content.aspx), along with some notes on their use.  And there are many more vendors.